# karate 0.9.5 version doesnot print the entire payload with authorization in cucumber report anymore

Tags: karate

karate 0.9.5 version doesnot print the entire payload with authorization in cucumber report anymore.
With version 0.8.0 whenever a payload is posted irrespective of the print statements, query used to post was printed as DocString in cucumber report but with version 0.9.5 it is only print statements which are visible.

Is there anything which is changed regarding this?